# Singular derivative matrix implies not one to one?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to show that if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n $ is continuously differentiable and that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ $Df(x)$ is singular implies that $f$ is not 1-1.

The singularity of the derivative clearly implies that at each point it has a nontrivial kernel and so my thinking was to use try to use the mean value theorem somehow with a vector which would make the derivative term vanish so that I get equality  between two different image points.  But in general the kernel of the derivative will depend on where it is evaluated in $\mathbb{R}^n$ so I haven't been able to do this directly since  I can't choose the kernel before choosing where to evaluate the derivative in the mean value theorem.

Maybe it's false though?  Counterexamples?

Comment: I'm really interested in knowing the solution to this problem, we have to show for a continuous curve through matrices with a fixed eigenvalue, we can find a continuous curve of eigenvectors corresponding to that eigenvalue. In our case that eigenvalue will be $0$ but it should work more generally. Once we do this, we have a differential equation for $x^{(1)}(t)$ which we can simply integrate to find $x(t)$ and which $f(x(t))$ will be constant.

Comment: I should mention that we have a curve through symmetric matrices.  This post might be relevant too:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/116123/how-to-find-define-eigenvectors-as-a-continuous-function-of-matrix

Comment: Sorry to spam the comments, here's another reference which may be useful to your problem.  http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01589439?LI=true.  This discusses the existence of continuous nullspace bases.  We don't need anything as strong as this but possibly contained inside the paper is conditions for when a single basis vector can be moved around continuously.

Comment: Maybe the [rank theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_rank_theorem#Constant_rank_theorem) is what you want?

Comment: @wj32 I think our biggest problem is that we don't have the locally-constant-rank hypothesis of the rank theorem. On the other hand, we merely need this hypothesis to hold at some point of $\mathbb{R}^n$, in which case yours or muzzlator's method would work unimpeded.

Comment: @wj32 On the other hand with some modest hypotheses we could get away with this, like for instance the existence of a point $x$ for which $df_x$ has nullity 1. Then the singularity of $df_x$ everywhere and the continuity properties of the eigenvalues imply that $df_x$ has nullity 1 in an neighborhood of $x$ and the rank theorem applies. A different argument is necessary for any higher nullity.

Comment: @ABlumenthal: Let $r$ be the maximum rank achieved at any point in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $x$ be such a point. Then there is a neighborhood of $x$ on which $Df$ has at least rank $r$, so $Df$ has exactly rank $r$ on this neighborhood.

Comment: @wj32 That'll do it.